# Ajax calls in jquery getting error:0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am making an ajax call to be used in jquerymobile. It is working fine in my local host , but when i uploaded it in the server, the ajax call returned an error:0

```
Code:
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#Joblist', function(){
if (navigator.onLine) 
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://sample.com/jobs",
        headers:{Authorization:authHeader},
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function(xml)
        {
            xmlJoblist=xml;
            localStorage.removeItem("jobList");
            var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);
            window.localStorage.setItem("jobList", xmlString);  
            viewJoblist(xml);
        },
        error: function(result) {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        console.log("error" + result.status + result.statusText); //result.status:0 
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is you AJAX call to a different domain? If so you are falling foul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/Same-origin_policy), and will need to use either JSONP or CORS, assuming either is available to you.

Comment: use chrome's dev tools, under the network tab monitor the ajax call and confirm that the server is giving X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN in the response header.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan  The same origin policy is handled in the server itself, that is why i was able to view in my system when it is uploaded in the server. I am getting this error when running the app in android web browser.

Comment: @user3393032 You have a misunderstanding of the same origin policy.  It is most definitely not handled on the server.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus But am getting the correct response when i run the app in my system once uploaded in server. If cross domain is the issue, then it should have given the error in my systems web browser, right. The error is thrown when i run the app in android mobile web browser. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you do some reading on the same origin policy and CORS.  There are many great resources on google and SO.